# Will my Spring Data Jpa method return all foreign fields?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

If I have a table like this :

```
Client
private Long int;
private String name;
@ManyToOne(mappedBy="otherField")
private Address addresses;
```

And I Create a repository that extends JPA Repository. Given the name of the client, I want to get as results also the Address Table fields.

Using the method 
Client findByName(String name)

Will my this also return all the fields that are on the Address Table ?
Like:

```
Address
private Long id;
private String city;
private Int code;
private String street;
```

Comment: This behavior is extensively explained in the docs of hibernate or other JPA implementations. You should read them.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`docs`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies)

> The Hibernate recommendation is to statically mark all associations
>   lazy and to use dynamic fetching strategies for eagerness. This is
>   unfortunately at odds with the JPA specification which defines that
>   all one-to-one and many-to-one associations should be eagerly fetched
>   by default. Hibernate, as a JPA provider, honors that default.

So Hibernate behaves the same as JPA:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

Also take a look at the JPA sepcifications [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1508662528_f2ec43b8f8e20c7d3ccf9f5d54c66f6a).